# How to get my IP address

Tags: shell-script

I want to show my IP above but I found the problem: eth0: error fetching, can someone help me pls

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "%{F#2495e7} %{F#ffffff}$(/usr/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet " | awk '{print $2}')%{u-}"
```

Comment: What do you mean by my IP? A network interface can have one or more IPv4 or IPv6 addresses. So a host can have one or more IPv4 or IPv6 addresses on one or more networks which those interfaces connect them to, but they generally have several. For instance, most hosts will have a `127.0.0.1` IPv4 address and `::1` IPv6 address on the loopback internal network.

Comment: `eth0` used to be the name of the first ethernet network interface found on a system by Linux, but on many modern Linux-based systems, it's automatically renamed to something else.

Comment: `Can someone please help me i'm stuck` is not a question about Linux  ... please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: so, on the system I tried, the error `ifconfig` gives if pointed at an interface that doesn't exist, is e.g. "eth99: error fetching interface information: Device not found". Now, you quoted that first part in your post, but I wonder if you read the full message?

Answer (score 1):

You can see IP addresses with `ip addr show`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enxb827eb315364: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:31:53:64 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.18/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute enxb827eb315364
```

Here we have two interfaces: loopback `lo` with IPv4 address `127.0.0.1`, and ethernet `enxb827eb315364` with IPv4 address `192.168.1.18`. There are no IPv6 addresses listed because this system doesn't run IPv6.

If you want a list of just the IP addresses themselves, for example to process programmatically, you could use something like this,

```
ip --json addr show | jq -r '.[] | select(.ifname != "lo") | .addr_info[].local'

192.168.1.18
```

Be aware that a systems may have more than one IP address, even in a situation where it has only one external interface. Multiple addresses, whether IPv4 or IPv6,  will be listed one per line.

Comment: `select(.link_type != "loopback")` or even better on addresses with scope other than `host` (or with `global` scope depending on what one really wants) may be more relevant than filtering by the name of the interface.

Comment: See also `ip --json addr show up` to limit to interfaces that are up.